# Removing a row from a sql table after time PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a logging sql database and I want to clear the logs after one day. 
As an example what I want to do is someone visits the website it logs there login info and how long they where on the website but after 24 hours I would like it to clear the row that the logging code made.I know there are ways to do this in SQL but me being new to both sql and php dont know how to convert that or do it in php. Is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: Do you want to clear the login history of the user after one day or make a user logged out after 24 hrs?

Comment: i want to clear the login history of the user after one day